# Two Related Windows 7 Issues

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update, troubleshooting, reboot

I have a Windows 7 laptop with two seemingly related issues.  First, when I turn the machine on, it reboots into Startup Repair before I can log into Windows.  After it runs, Windows loads normally.  The full sequence can be seen [here](https://vimeo.com/356805571), including the Startup Repair diagnosis and repair log (14:00).  I would paste the log if possible, but it runs outside of Windows.

The second issue is that my security monthly quality rollup Windows update is failing.  [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdQsx.png) is the history, which shows that the August rollup has failed multiple times.  The July rollup, by contrast, was successful.

One course of action that has been recommended to me based on the Startup Repair diagnosis and repair log is to rebuild the BCD by [following these instructions](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-rebuild-the-bcd-in-windows-2624508).  This would be based on the idea that the Startup Repair bug is primary, perhaps causing the Windows update bug.  I wonder if the reverse causal order is more likely, however, since Startup Repair only shows up when the update icon is present on the Shut down button (which is generally every day, but seems to be avoidable by not connecting to the Internet).

Am I correct that the Windows update bug is causing the Startup Repair bug, not vice-versa, and that rebuilding the BCD would thus be irrelevant?  If so, how can I fix the Windows update bug?  Can I just wait for September's quality rollup, or will it likely fail until August's succeeds?

Microsoft Security Essentials and chkdsk on the C drive both come back healthy.  The Windows update error code is 80242016.

Comment: Have you scanned for malware?  Have you run a chkdsk on the C drive?

Comment: In order to provide a helpful answer, please provide the error code you receive, when you attempt to install the update that is failing

Comment: Are you positive that the update that is failing isn’t already installed?  0x80242016 is sometimes caused by that condition

Comment: @Ramhound Very interesting, judging by the second link in the question, it looks like the update was installed successfully on 8/21 after multiple failures, and then continued to fail after that.  I'm not 100% positive though, as the monthly quality rollups don't appear in the View installed updates window.

Comment: @user1083311 - They should be listed.  They certainly are listed on all my Windows 10 systems.

Comment: @Ramhound Hmm, looks like some appear in the history and some don't?  This should provide a good picture of what's going on:  https://i.imgur.com/YfMLnr2.png

Comment: If you have an update that continues to be installed, despite the fact it's already installed, a workaround solution is to perform a Windows Update reset.  This will of course remove the update history, but it should, prevent the same update from being installed twice.

Answer (score -1):

*Am I correct that Windows update bug is causing the Startup Repair bug, not vice-versa,*

Windows Updates do not cause a Startup Repair sequence on a machine that is running properly.

*Can I just wait for September's quality rollup, or will it likely fail until August's succeeds?*

I am not certain but I think so. There was an issue on August Patch Tuesday (past) for machines running Symantec Endpoint Protection or Norton.  That was fixed fairly quickly. September Patch Tuesday is soon, so see if the September update fixes the issue.

Comment: The author’s inability to update their system is absolutely the reason their installation must go through repair process.  Waiting for the next update might be worth while but in all likelihood they will continue to be unable to install updates unless they find the cause of their problems.  This answer absolutely does not indicate what the author should do to install the update that is failing.